# Как заменить `html` тег `<a> </a>` на кликабельную ссылку в TextView?

Tags: android, регулярные-выражения, jsoup, android-textview

Я пробовал делать так:

1. Создаю класс `Elements` из `Jsoup` и делаю `text.select("a")`
2. Затем делаю `foreach` для каждой ссылки и в тексте (Перед этим через `text.html()`) делаю

   ```
   text.replaceFirst("/<a\\\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\\\/a>/Um", "\tССЫЛКА!!!!!\t");
   ```

И по возращении форматированного текста добавляю его в `TextView` и после этого делаю

```
mTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Первая проблема в том, что регулярное выражение не заменяется на другую строку.
Может есть способ менее изощренный?

Comment: В интернетах есть много разных сайтов, где можно поиграться регулярками. Например вот http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/

Comment: @rjhdby Да дело в том, что на сайте выделяет нужные участки, а в приложении нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `Html.fromHtml` и не мучайтесь с регулярками, они тут не нужны:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
```

К сожалению если ссылки у вас относительные, то они не будут срабатывать при клике, но это можно исправить с помощью метода (взято [отсюда](http://androblip.huiges.nl/2010/11/28/handling-html-in-a-textview/)):

```
public Spanned correctLinkPaths(Spanned spantext) {
    Object[] spans = spantext.getSpans(0, spantext.length(), Object.class);
    for (Object span : spans) {
        int start = spantext.getSpanStart(span);
        int end = spantext.getSpanEnd(span);
        int flags = spantext.getSpanFlags(span);
        if (span instanceof URLSpan) {
            URLSpan urlSpan = (URLSpan) span;
            if (!urlSpan.getURL().startsWith("http")) {
                if (urlSpan.getURL().startsWith("/")) {
                    urlSpan = new URLSpan("http://domain+path" + urlSpan.getURL());
                } else {
                    urlSpan = new URLSpan("http://domain+path/" + urlSpan.getURL());
                }
            }
            ((Spannable) spantext).removeSpan(span);
            ((Spannable) spantext).setSpan(urlSpan, start, end, flags);
        }
    }
    return spantext;
}
```

`http://domain+path` замените на ваш основной домен, после чего изначальный код превращается в:

```
textView.setText(correctLinkPaths(Html.fromHtml(htmlText)));
```

Comment: `fromHtml()` возвращает `android.text.Spanned`. Добавил `toString()` возвращает как текст без ссылок. Вообще игнорирует `html` тэги. Дописывал `mTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` после `setText(htmlTextFormatted)` - не работает

Comment: Зачем вы `toString()` добавили? Вам `Spanned` и надо в `setText` пихать. Это форматированный текст, который в том числе умеет и ссылки подсвечивать. А `toString()` всё форматирование убирает.

Comment: Работает. Только он почему-то по тапу на ссылку, пишет, что ни одного подходящего приложения не найдено, хотя ссылки обычные, для браузера

Comment: Покажите пример ваших обычных ссылок. Полностью тег <a>.

Comment: `<a href="https://25.mvd.ru/news/item/7748412/" target="_blank">сообщает</a>`   `<a href="/accidents/2016/05/11/147225/" target="_blank">Напомним</a>` По ходу дела `target` виноват

Comment: А ошибки нет, сейчас скрин с телефона добавлю в вопрос

Comment: По обоим ссылкам не работает? По первой должен, а вторая относительная, их да, не обработать, так как там нет схемы и домена. К сожалению эта штука умеет переходить только по полным ссылкам.

Comment: ну тогда конкатенировать придется с доменом. Блин, это придется делать проверки на неполные ссылки. Похоже без регулярок никак

Comment: можно и без регулярок, дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, делал бы сейчас паттерн для `regex`

Answer (score 0):

```
changedText = text.replaceFirst("<a[^>]*>[^<]*</a>", "\tССЫЛКА!!!!!\t")
```